# Adding multiple lines breaks in android string file using CDATA and <br/> tag?

Tags: android, xml, string, android-layout, line-breaks

I need consecutive line breaks in a string on a android textview.

```
<string name="message">
<![CDATA[menu:<br /><br />1.One item<br />2.Two item<br/><br/>Done]]>
</string>
```

I want this to be rendered like:

```
Menu:

1.One item 
2.Two item

Done
```

But its not working two line breaks by using two `<br /><br />` is not working i got the output like

```
Menu:1.One item
2.Two itemDone
```

Two `<br />` is not working only one `<br />` is working properly in `CDATA` tag in android string file why ?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the menu is a `p` tag. E.g `<![CDATA[menu:<p><br /><br />1.One item<br />2.Two item<br/><br/>Done</p>]]>`

Comment: Include how you render the text.  For example this renders just as desired: `tv.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(getString(R.string.message),HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));`